# Why does it seem more natural to think of $r$ as a function of $\theta$, rather than the other way around?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polar-coordinates

When teaching functions in polar coordinates, the nearly universal practice is to consider functions of the form $r = f(\theta)$.  I think I have never seen any examples in which $\theta$ is expressed as a function of $r$.  My intuition tells me that the usual setup is more ``natural'' in some sense than the latter, but I am not sure whether that is just because it's what I'm used to, or if I am responding to some intrinsic difference between the two cases.  Is there any good reason why, for instance, it seems more natural to write $r = \sqrt{\theta}$ than to write $\theta = r^2$, despite the fact that they are (obviously) equivalent?

**Edited to add:** Here is an example of what I mean.  Consider the function $\theta = \cos (r)$.  It has a very cool graph:
[image]

Intuitively, if we think of $r$ as the independent variable, and ask how $\theta$ depends on $r$, the description is quite simple: as we move outwards from the origin, the angle oscillates back and forth between a minimum angle of $-1$ radian and a maximum angle of $1$ radian.  This is a perfectly reasonable function to think about, graph, and study.  And yet functions like this are (as far as I can tell) completely absent both from textbooks and from usual instruction.  I find this strange, and am wondering if anybody has any thoughts on why.

Comment: I wonder if it's just that most curves people have thought of are more easily expressed as $r={}$than $\theta={\!}$?

Comment: Here's a simple polynomial, $\theta=r^3+r$. https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Gvc.jpg Nearly breaks Desmos (it doesn't even support doing it this way, I had to mess with it to get it to work). How much information about the polynomial are you getting from it?

Comment: Just speculating, but polar coordinates presumably arose from sea navigation. In that setting, it's more natural to take the independent variable to be the controllable one (the direction of sight/travel/radar heading) and the dependent variable to be the measured one (distance to the destination, obstacle, enemy). <> For whatever reason, it never occurred to me to look at graphs $\theta = f(r)$ of highly oscillatory functions $f$. That _is_ fun...!

Comment: +1 also : $\theta = \cos(r)$ is a very cool function, that I (for one) never thought of, because of my blind spot, in presuming that the magnitude should be a function of the angle.

Comment: @user2661923 Said "blind spot" is precisely what motivates the question. We all seem to have it; where does it come from?

Comment: Indeed $\theta=\cos r$ is a very cool function.... definitely agree

Answer (score 3):

Addendum-2 added to respond to the OP's editing of their original posting, re the function $\theta = \cos(r)$.

---

Addendum added to respond to a comment question.

---

Because a function must map each element in its domain to only a single element in its range.

For example, consider the function $r = \cos(\theta)$.

Then, for each angle $\theta$, there is a specific value $r$.  However, the function does not have an inverse.  For example if you try to express $\theta = g(r)$, then what is $g(1/2)$?  Even if you restrict the range to $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, for example, would $g(1/2)$ equal $\pi/3$ or $5\pi/3$?

One approach, is to force the inverse function $g(r)$ to exist by requiring that the range of $\theta$ be limited to $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi.$  In fact, this is exactly what is done with the Arccos function, and for this very reason.

Normally, when you have a function like $r = f(\theta)$, you want $\theta$ to *at least* take on the values in some half-open interval of width $(2\pi)$, and perhaps allow $\theta$ to take on the value of any real number.

By specifying $r = f(\theta)$, instead of attempting to specify $\theta = g(r)$, you don't have to worry whether a specific value of $r$ is associated with more than one value of $\theta$.

---

**Edit**
Certainly, you can contrive functions, like $r = 2\theta + 4$, where the considerations of the previous section are a non-issue.  However, normally, a function like $r = f(\theta)$ will be used when the function $f$ is performing some trigonometric action, such as some interaction between the sine and cosine functions.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment question of Akiva Weinberger.

> Don't we have the opposite sort of problem normally? $r=\sqrt{θ}$ and $r=\sqrt{θ + 2\pi}$ give the same curve.

First of all, $~\displaystyle r = \sqrt{\theta} ~$ is only defined on $~\theta \geq 0~$, while
$\displaystyle ~ r = \sqrt{\theta + 2\pi} ~$ is only defined on $~\theta \geq -2\pi.~$

Then, $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{\theta} ~$ is not equal to $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{\theta + 2\pi}. ~$

Second of all, the $~r = f(\theta)~$ approach is normally only used when $~f~$
relates to trigonometry
functions.

So, consider the alternate of function of
$~r = f(\theta) = \sqrt{|\cos \theta|}~$.

This function does not present any *difficulty*.  It is merely a function that is not injective.  The situation analogizes to setting $y = f(x) = |x| ~: x \in \Bbb{R}.$  You wouldn't be able to construct the inverse function $x = g(y)$, because (for example) $g(5)$ would ambiguously refer to $+5,$ or $-5$.

In the same way, when $~r = f(\theta) = \sqrt{|\cos \theta|}~$,
$f(\theta) = f(\theta + 2\pi)$. 
Notice what happens if you try to construct the alternative *corresponding mapping* of $\theta = g(r).$  What would $g(1)$ map to, $\theta = 0, \theta = \pi, \theta = 2\pi,$ or what?

You could not use the corresponding mapping to construct an inverse function because the original mapping was not injective.  This is typical for $r = f(\theta)$ functions that involve trigonometric operations.

---

In a similar vein, consider the polar function $r = \cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta).$

---

**Addendum-2** 
Reacting to the OP's editing of their original posting, re $\theta = \cos(r)$.

This is a function that I never thought of, because of my blind spot that the magnitude should be a function of the angle.

Comment: Don't we have the opposite sort of problem normally? $r=\sqrt\theta$ and $r=\sqrt{\theta+2\pi}$ give the same curve.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.

Comment: Sure, obviously there are non-injective functions $r=f(\theta)$ that can't be inverted. But the same is true in the other direction, too:  $\theta = \cos(r)$ is a perfectly reasonable non-injective function that cannot be inverted. And yet I don't think I have ever encountered an example like this in a textbook.  Why is that?

Comment: @mweiss because, starting from Analytical Geometry, through Real Analysis, and into Complex Analysis, polar coordinates are expressed as $$(r,\theta) = (x,y) \iff r\cos(\theta) = x, r\sin(\theta) = y$$ or $$re^{i\theta} = [r\cos(\theta)] + i[r\sin(\theta)] = (x + iy) \in \Bbb{C}.$$  People are accustomed to the harmless consistency of using a greek letter to express the angle, and $r$ to express a magnitude.

Comment: @user2661923 I am not suggesting that $r$ should denote the angle and that $\theta$ should denote the radius -- that would be madness. I am proposing that we could consider functions in which the angle is an explicit function of the radius (and a non-invertible function, to boot, so that the relation cannot simply be rewritten in the other order).  See my edit the the original question for an example of what I mean.